# PHP Find correct JSON element via search

Tags: php, json

OK let's say I have this example of JSON

```
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Random Title 1",
            "description": "Random Description 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Random Title 2",
            "description": "Random Description 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "title": "Random Title 3",
            "description": "Random Description 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Do you notice how the IDs are spaced out? So if I wanted to get the 2nd one "Random Title 2" it wouldn't be `[4]` but `[2]`. Some of my JSON "ids" are skipping because I edit the JSON file... ANyway right now, I want to get the title of a JSON element based on the `id`. Each JSON element has a different ID.

Here's what I do right now:

```
$string = file_get_contents("achievements.json");
$json_a=json_decode($string,true);

$getID = $ID_number;

$getit = $json_a['testJSON'][$getID]['title'];
```

Now, I have the `$ID_number` but it won't be the same as the array number. The above is wrong... how do I fix it so I search by `id`

Comment: With [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) and an [`if`](http://php.net/if).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($json_a['tstJSON'] as $element) {
    if ($element['id'] == $getID) {
        $getit = $element['title'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this was easy enough and simple. Thank you.

Comment: You do know that you're doing an assignment in an if statement right?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my answer:

```
<?php

$json = <<<EOF
{
    "result": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Random Title 1",
            "description": "Random Description 1"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "title": "Random Title 2",
            "description": "Random Description 2"
        },
        {
            "id": 10,
            "title": "Random Title 3",
            "description": "Random Description 3"
        }
    ]
}
EOF;

$arr = json_decode($json,true);
$res = $arr['result'];

function search_by_key_and_value($array, $key, $value)
{
    $results = array();

    if (is_array($array))
    {
        if (isset($array[$key]) && $array[$key] == $value)
            $results[] = $array;

        foreach ($array as $subarray)
            $results = array_merge($results, search_by_key_and_value($subarray, $key, $value));
    }

    return $results;
}

print("<pre>");
print_r($res);
print("</pre>");

print("<hr />");
$result = search_by_key_and_value($res,"id",4);

print("<pre>");
print_r($result);
print("</pre>");

?>
```

Hope this is what you need